# how not to replace certain characters in a string in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, string

Let's say replace characters but not last "4" with "!" in a random string.
or replace characters but not middle "3" with "@" in a random string.

*example 1:*

**input(hdasd1234)**

**output(!!!!!1234)**

*example 2:*

**input(asadfe455)**

**output(@@@dfe@@@)**

```
x = str(input())

y = "!" * (len(x) - 4) + x[-4:]

print(x)
```

This code is not working.

Comment: There should be plenty of answers to this question on the site.  Try a few of the answers and post your code if you get stuck.

Comment: Can you please provide cause I haven't find any answers that explained this kind of problem so far.I beg pardon for my no success.

Comment: In the function are you given certain characters to replace or specific positions to replace with '!' or '@'?

Comment: specific positions. I want to replace last 4 characters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a very basic, direct solution, you can do this:

> Example one:

```
string = input() #input automatically returns a string, so there's no need for str()
y = '!' * (len(string)-5) + string[4:]print (y) #remember to print y, not string because y is the modified version of your string
```

> And example two

```
string = input()
y = "@" * 3 + string[3:6] + "@" * 3
print (y)
```

For a more flexible method to this approach, you should create a function. Assuming you are given the positions of where to change the string in a list, the string, and the specific marker to replace `string[n]` with, this should be fairly simple:

```
def replace_chars(string, positions, s):
    new_string = []
    for i in range(len(string)):
        if i not in positions: #Checking if position, i, is not one of the marked positions
            new_string.append(string[i])
        else: #If it is a marked positions, append it with the marker, s, or more specifically '@'
            new_string.append(s)
    return ''.join(new_string) #Make the list a string
```

This could be written in a 1-2 lines long function with one line for loops but this formatting is better for readability. But if you were to do it in 1-2 lines, it would look like this:

```
def replace_chars(string, positions, s):
    new_string = [string[i] if i not in positions else s for i in range(len(string))]
    return ''.join(new_string)
```

Comment: That's too much for me to digest.Still a beginner.

Comment: Oh, sorry about that. Try doing the first example one that's flexible for any string given!

Comment: These are the main problems with your code: You try to make the input a string which is redundant given that input() returns a string, you print out x instead of y, which is the actual, modified string, and you write x[-4:] which doesn't make sense, you should just write x[4:] which just means go from the fourth character in the string to the last.

Answer (score 0):

The code is printing the value of x which is not modified.
Your code logic is creating a new variable y with the result and the x is unmodified.
However,you are printing the value of x which is the exact same input.
The logic seems to be working and the result is correct for the value of y.

Please check on that.
If any issues,please post the error log or the results.